# How to add objects to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, javascript-objects

I am trying to add objects formatted as `{title: value}` to an array. I wrote the following function

```js
const newResults = resultData.map(result => {
  let results = [];
  if (result.INTELLCONT.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.INTELLCONT.length; i++) {
      results.push({
        title: result.INTELLCONT[i].TITLE._text,
      });
    }
  } else {
    results.push({
      title: result.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text,
    });
  }
  return results;
});
```

But the array being returned looks like this

```
[Array(3), Array(1), Array(4), Array(1), Array(2), Array(1), Array(4)]
```

I want it to look like this

```
[{title: value}, {title: value}, {title: value}, {title: value}, {title: value}, ... ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `.map().flat()`.

Comment: because you are pushing arrays into an index in an array, that is how map works. You probably want reduce or use concat

Comment: The line with `result.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text` is accurate? Because it seems like `result.INTELLCONT` is an array and you'd need to change that to `result.INTELLCONT[0].TITLE._text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With map you are pusing an array into each index. So it is working as expected. Use reduce instead of map so you will just push it to one array and not have to do extra work afterwards to flatten it.

```
const newResults = resultData.reduce((results, result) => {
  if (result.INTELLCONT.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.INTELLCONT.length; i++) {
      results.push({
        title: result.INTELLCONT[i].TITLE._text,
      });
    }
  } else {
    results.push({
      title: result.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text,
    });
  }
  return results;
}, []);
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `resultData.reduce` instead of `resultData.map`?

Answer (score 1):

As [@random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631979/how-to-add-objects-to-array/59632091#comment105426310_59631979) stated, you can use add [`.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) after your call to `.map` since that would create an array of arrays, which you'd want to flatten after.

---

Alternatively, you can do it in a single pass by just adding the items into a new array:

```js
const resultData = [
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "A"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "B"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "C"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "D"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "E"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "F"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "G"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "H"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "I"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "J"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "K"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "L"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "M"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "N"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "O"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "P"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "Q"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "R"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "S"}}]},
];

const newResults = [];
resultData.forEach(result => {
  if (result.INTELLCONT.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.INTELLCONT.length; i++) {
      newResults.push({
        title: result.INTELLCONT[i].TITLE._text,
      });
    }
  } else {
    newResults.push({
      title: result.INTELLCONT[0].TITLE._text,
    });
  }
});

console.log(newResults);
```

---

If `resultData` can be iterated through, you can simplify even more by using [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const resultData = [
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "A"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "B"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "C"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "D"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "E"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "F"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "G"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "H"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "I"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "J"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "K"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "L"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "M"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "N"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "O"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "P"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "Q"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "R"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "S"}}]},
];

const newResults = resultData.flatMap(result => result.INTELLCONT.map(r => ({title: r.TITLE._text})));

console.log(newResults)
```

Alternatively:

```js
const resultData = [
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "A"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "B"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "C"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "D"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "E"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "F"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "G"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "H"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "I"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "J"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "K"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "L"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "M"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "N"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "O"}}]},
  {INTELLCONT: [{TITLE: {"_text": "P"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "Q"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "R"}}, {TITLE: {"_text": "S"}}]},
];

const newResults2 = resultData.flatMap(result => result.INTELLCONT).map(r => ({title: r.TITLE._text}));

console.log(newResults2)
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and according to the documentation

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results

so basically, you are doing:

```
let results = [];
.....
return results
```

and therefore, each entry of your array will be converted(mapped) to an array.

in order to solve this, you can use [Flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) in order to get what you want.

```
const newResults = resultData.map(result => {
  let results = [];
  if (result.INTELLCONT.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.INTELLCONT.length; i++) {
      results.push({
        title: result.INTELLCONT[i].TITLE._text,
      });
    }
  } else {
    results.push({
      title: result.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text,
    });
  }
  return results;
})
.flat();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Array.reduce` instead of `Array.map` because `map` returns one value for each element of the input array.

```js
let accumulatorInitiator = []
const newResults = resultData.reduce((accumulator, result) => {;
  if (result.INTELLCONT.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.INTELLCONT.length; i++) {
      accumulator.push({
        title: result.INTELLCONT[i].TITLE._text,
      });
    }
  } else {
    accumulator.push({
      title: result.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text,
    });
  }
  return accumulator;
}, accumulatorInitiator);
```